# Angle Hit Comparision: Fails to detect hit

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I am attempting to write a function that will tell me if an angle lies within 2 other angles. When say *'if an angle lies within 2 other angles'* I mean for example, if I have the 2 angles 0 and 90 then 45 would lie between those angles but -20(or 99) would not.

**My Problem:** My function doesn't seem to be detecting when 2 angles lie within 2 angles when it should. I'm not sure if my function works for negative angles aswell?

**What do I need to change to get my function working correctly?**

```
bool is_angle_between(int target, int angle1, int angle2)
{
  // Post: Return true if target lies between the 2 angles

  int iTarget = (360 + (target % 360)) % 360;
  int iAngle1 = (3600000 + angle1) % 360;
  int iAngle2 = (3600000 + angle2) % 360;

  if (iAngle1 < iAngle2)
    if (iAngle1 <= iTarget && iTarget <= iAngle2)
      return true;
  else if (iAngle1 <= iTarget || iTarget <= iAngle2)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `target > angle1 && target < angle2`? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @StackUnderflow will that work if angle1 is the larger angle? The variables angle1 and angle2 are not sorted by their size they can be any value. Not sure that will work for is_angle_between(45, 90, 0);?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like this should work:

```
if (iAngle1 < iAngle2) {
    if (iAngle1 <= iTarget && iTarget <= iAngle2) {
        return true;
    }
}
else {
    if (iAngle2 <= iTarget && iTarget <= iAngle1) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Note that the braces here help ensure that the else matches the if you intend it to.  Your original code is indented as you want it to match, but that isn't how it's parsed.

Answer (score 1):

This question only has to do with testing whether an integer lies between within the range of two other integers. Since we do not know whether `angle1` or `angle2` is the larger value, I would do something like this:

```
bool is_angle_between(int target, int angle1, int angle2)
{
    return (target > angle1 && target < angle2) ||
           (target > angle2 && target < angle1);
}
```

Comment: The answer is wrong, the order matters because angles are circular.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to rotate the interval so that all numbers you compare are positive:

```
int rTarget = ((target - angle1) % 360 + 360) % 360;
int rAngle2 = ((angle2 - angle1) % 360 + 360) % 360;
return 0 <= rAngle1 && rAngle1 <= rAngle2;
```

Otherwise you will get into trouble near 0 = 360 degrees.

BTW, you should avoid unnecessary `if` statements, as branching can be expensive.